# javascript: classes and get methods before class syntax

Tags: javascript, function, class, get

i am creating a class in a old way without the new class syntax like this:

```
function User(name, lastname){
  this.name = name;
  this.lastname = lastname;
  this.fullname = function(){
    return this.name+' '+this.lastname;
  }
}
```

i would like to use fullname as a get method. but i don't get how to do  it.

for example i would like to call it this way:

```
var u = new User('dario', 'developer');
console.log(u.fullname);
```

basically without parentheses. I know with the new class syntax you can use the get keyword. but how can i do it with this way of creating classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (BEWARE: it's supported from ES5 onward, otherwise you have to make it thorugh an object literal declaration, but that would need to change your current code a bit more) if you want to keep your current scenario.

```js
function User(name, lastname){
  this.name = name;
  this.lastname = lastname;
  Object.defineProperty(this, "fullname", {
    get: function() {
      return this.name+' '+this.lastname;
    }
  });
}

var u = new User('dario', 'developer');
console.log(u.fullname);
```